# I am getting access denied to internal hard drive and failed to enumerate objects

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, permissions

On Tuesday I noticed I was getting access denied to my data drive. I am running Windows 10. I have 3 other drives. The problem is only with this drive. I have gone through the properties and went into advanced security settings to change owner (as it had changed), and checked replace child object permission entries box. when I hit reply I still get an error, 'failed to enumerate objects in container. Access is denied. I then went to elevated CMD and tried:

takeown /F "full path of folder or drive" /A /R /D Y
and
icacls "full path of folder or drive" /setowner "Administrators" /T /C

I am logged in as an administrator. No matter what I read and try, I am still getting access denied to the hard drive. I did also delete the last several windows updates that were installed around that time. any advice would be helpful.

Comment: Sounds like the drive is failing

Comment: Test the drive with a SMART tool.

Comment: I ran SMART software. It passed everything. I do not think the drive is failing. I forgot to mention when I plugged another  3.5" drive into one of my esata ports I got access denied on that also. Same with an external drive I have. So it's actually 3 drives.

Comment: the 3.5" hard drive I plugged into an esata port, after I got access denied, I wiped the drive and reformatted it. It sounds like a permissions issue. I just do not know how to fix it.